# Why does serverspec connect to the localhost instead of the remote host

Tags: ruby, serverspec

My serverspec example, setup using serverspec-init, then I generated this simple test file ./spec/altspf01/sample_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe command( '/bin/hostname -s' ) do
   its(:stdout) { should match /atlspf01/ }
end
```

I expect it to ssh to a remote host (atlspf01) and check its hostname (atlspf01). Instead it connects to the localhost (ltipc682).

```
  1) Command "/bin/hostname -s" stdout should match /atlspf01/
     Failure/Error: its(:stdout) { should match /atlspf01/ }
       expected "ltipc682\n" to match /atlspf01/
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -/atlspf01/
       +ltipc682
```

What have I done wrong?

All code here: https://gist.github.com/neilhwatson/a3f4a26ad8cf27d62307

Comment: Please post the *relevant* part of the code in your question instead of simply putting a link to it.

Comment: I don't know the relevant part.

Comment: Then, please strip down your code, create a minimal reproducible example, and add the code to your question. Answering a question on SO that doesn't contain essential information doesn't make much sense - the document referred to in the link might be removed, which would render the question meaningless for future readers.

Comment: @neil Does it have the same behavior if you run it via `rake` ?

Comment: @egwspiti no, when using rake it seems to ssh correctly. I'm too new to Serverspec to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serverspec's specs should be run via `rake`. Otherwise, the spec doesn't know the target host.

However, if you wish to run it via `rspec`, you could use this workaround:

`env TARGET_HOST='atlspf01' rspec spec/atlspf01/sample_spec.rb`

Hope this helps.